# Send request to server side on the text using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to send request on server side `onFocus` event but my method is not calling, really confused, tried jquery ajax for that but all failed is there any other possible way to send request on server side using asp.net textbox onFocus event?

asp.net website project is created for work.

Ajax method code

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "About.aspx/GetRes",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

Method which is calling

```
Public Function GetRes() As String
    Return "I am calling GetRes method"
End Function
```

Comment: please paste the code here

Comment: @KD please now suggest me.

Comment: are you able to access About.aspx/GetRes page directly if you paste the url in browser? and have you wraped your event binding in $(function(){}) callback of jquery?

Comment: It doesn't show GetRes result it shows About.aspx page

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to access the supplied url via browser properly then please try this..

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "About.aspx/GetRes",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

Also, i'm considering that your event biding is wrapped under the document.ready callback

and make the server side method like this

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetRes() As String
    Return "I am calling GetRes method"
End Function
```

Comment: I tried to access my url. His response should be I am calling GetRes method but it shows About.aspx page

Comment: look at this link, it could be helpful to you
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ please let me know if you still facing problem

Comment: Still getting the same issue :(

Comment: Did you make the `WebMethod` changes?

Comment: did you see any AJAX request from console?

Answer (score 2):

You can only call PageMethods like that.

Such methods should be static(Shared) and have the `WebMethod` attribute.

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetRes() As String
  Return "I am calling GetRes method"
End Function
```